# How to use Twitter Bootstrap in Laravel 4 project

Tags: composer-php

I have a Laravel 4 project I'd like to use twitter bootstrap for.

My `composer.json` looks like:

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.1.*",
    "codeception/codeception": "1.8.1",
    "twbs/bootstrap": "v3.0.3"
},
```

I'd like to use the CSS/JS in my project which means the files need to be served from the `public` directory.  I know I could copy/paste or download the files directly, but that would defeat the purpose of composer.  What's the correct procedure to serve these assets up from the public directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shortest answer is "don't".  It's not a recommended way to handle assets, not even by Composer's author himself.  Using something like `grunt` or just including bootstrap from it's CDN will yield better benefits.

If you *insist* on doing it this way, creating a symlink may be easiest and I believe someone has published a "Laravel Asset Manager" on packagist.org.

Answer (score 1):

Composer isn't really designed to be a package management system for assets. [Bower](https://github.com/bower/bower) would be a much better choice and shares a similar json file for managing assets.

Answer (score 0):

Try an [asset manager](https://github.com/teepluss/laravel4-asset).

You should also serve them from [a CDN](http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/).